# How to repeat text matched by a regex?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I'm trying to add log4j to a legacy software using eclipse search/replace.

The idea is to find all class declarations and replace them by, the declaration itself plus the definition of the logger in the next line.

search

```
".*class ([A-Z][a-z]+).*\{"
```

replace:

```
"final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger($1.class);"
```

How can I prepend the matched pattern (the class definition) to the replace string?

Comment: Thanks for you answers, saved me a few hours. I use now "$0\n\n\tfinal static Logger log = Logger.getLogger($1.class);" as replace string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this:

search:

```
(.*class ([A-Z][a-z]+).*\{)
```

replace:

```
$1\Rfinal static Logger log = Logger.getLogger($2.class);
```

Comment: Notice the \R which creates the line break. And maybe you would like to add some tabs \t so the logger declaration is indented.

Answer (score 1):

You can always capture the whole thing and put it in. The inner capture group lives in a second backreference.

Find:

`(.*class ([A-Z][a-z]+).*\{)`

Replace with:

`$1 final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger($2.class);`